# Understanding Limits

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

> A limit is the value that a function approaches as the input approaches some value.

The way I understand limits, is they look at how a function behaves as it gets closer and closer to some value. However, if this is the case, why does it make sense for us to talk about the derivative of a particular point?

Consider first principles. $h$ shrinks and approaches zero. However, it shouldn't ever reach zero as this would result in division by zero. So once again, how does the derivative of an exact point make sense?

Furthermore, in first principles what allows us to manipulate it, such that the $h$ cancels out. It seems like this is just a cheap trick to avoid division by zero.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The intuition must be supported by the rigorous definition of [Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)).

Comment: Does it help if you think of the derivative at $x$ as a short way of saying that you are interested in the limit of the differential quotient at $x$?

Comment: Concerning derivative: in order to compute the speed at a moment $t_0$ you calculate the distance covered in a short interval of time  from $t_0$ to $t_0+h$ and you divide by $h.$ So it does not make sense to take $h=0.$ You let $h$ tend to $0,$ to get the actual speed at the moment $t_0.$

Comment: What do  you mean by why it makes sense? It's the definition, and some functions have limits and some don't. It might help you to look at Leibniz's approach, with infinitesimals.

Answer (score 3):

Good question. It's been asked since Calculus was invented: [The Analyst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Analyst) criticizes "... these Fluxions? The Velocities of evanescent Increments? And what are these same evanescent Increments? They are neither finite Quantities nor Quantities infinitely small, nor yet nothing. May we not call them the ghosts of departed quantities?[4]

Part of the problem is the lack of a rigorous treatment of limits at the time. The rigorous theorems involved rely less on $h=0$ than the idea that $h$ is less than any positive number and greater than any negative number.

For $f(x)=x^2$, We start with $\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h}=h+2x$. Then let $h=0$ to get $2x$. What sense does it make to let $h$ be zero since we divided by it in the first step?

A more rigorous treatment asks what happens to $|(2x+h)-2x| $ if $0<|h|<\delta$

$0<|h|<\delta\implies -\delta<h<\delta \implies -\delta<h<\delta\implies2x-\delta<2x+h<2x+\delta$.

The expression on the right means we aren't concerned with what happens if $h=0$, but what happens to the quantity $2x-h$ if for a given range of $h$ about $0$.

For a given range of the error of $ (2x+h)$ and $2x$, we can find a range for $h$ so that $|(2x+h)-2x|<\epsilon$.

In other words for a given error tolerance $\epsilon>0$, we are assured that $-\epsilon < (2x+h)-2x<\epsilon$ if $-\epsilon<h<\epsilon$.

That means effectively the error can be made arbitrarily small. For any error, we can assure the difference between $2x$ and the ratio that defines the derivative is less than that quantity. $h$, the error term is less than any positive quantity and greater than any negative quantity so it is zero. So the division by zero can be avoided and still leave a meaning to the derivative.